# open webkit view in different viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to make an app for my mothers books where in the first viewcontroller there are images with buttons next to them that open a certain book in fullscreen. As much as I know I need a new viewcontroller to open webkitview in fullscreen. I managed to open webkitview in fullscreen through viewDidLoad() but I want to insert more than one book and that in a neet looking way.

All I need is to know how to tell the button to open the next viewcontroller where I spread webkitview over the whole display to make it act like fullscreen. Here is the code I did until now...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webViewDisplay: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "prayers", ofType: "pdf")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webViewDisplay.load(request)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, edit your post: Remove needless details (likes `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, `var webView = WKWebView()`).

Comment: ok, sorry, How do I edit a post?

Comment: haha, found it a second after I commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your WkWebView first but you can't do that from storyboard. Instead of outlet try to add WKWebView programmaticaly.

```
private var webView: WKWebView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
    view = webView
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "prayers", ofType: "pdf")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)
}
```